# Nested router not working

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, drf-nested-routers

I'm new to Django and am struggling to get nested routers working. Basically, I'm trying to model the endpoint `/api/v1/organizers/1/events/1`, where I have `Event` and `Organizer` models as follows:

```
class Event(models.Model):
    class Meta:
        db_table = 'events'

    STATUS_CHOICES = (
        ('scheduled', 'Scheduled'),
        ('completed', 'Completed'),
        ('cancelled', 'Cancelled')
    )

    name = models.TextField()
    purpose = models.TextField()
    date_time = models.DateTimeField()
    description = models.TextField()
    programme = models.TextField()
    entry_fee = models.DecimalField(max_digits=6, decimal_places=2)
    status = models.TextField(choices=STATUS_CHOICES)
    comments = models.TextField(null=True)
    people_invited = models.ManyToManyField('Contact', through='EventInvitation')
    organizer = models.ForeignKey('Organizer', on_delete=models.CASCADE)

class Organizer(models.Model):
    STATUS_CHOICES = (
        ('inactive', 'Inactive'),
        ('active', 'Active'),
    )

    class Meta:
        db_table = 'organizers'

    first_name = models.TextField()
    middle_name = models.TextField(null=True)
    last_name = models.TextField(null=True)
    email = models.OneToOneField('Email', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    company_name = models.TextField(null=True)
    company_description = models.TextField(null=True)
    password = models.TextField()
    login_token = models.TextField(null=True)
    registered_on = models.DateTimeField(null=True)
    status = models.TextField(choices = STATUS_CHOICES, default='inactive')
```

I created another app called `rest_api` to handle the API. The models are stored in an app called `shared_stuff`. Anyway, here's the project-level `urls.py` (don't mind the `front_end` app for now):

```
from django.conf.urls import include, url

urlpatterns = [    
    url(r'^api/v1/', include('rest_api.urls')),
    url(r'^', include('frontend.urls')),
]
```

And here's the `urls.py` from the app `rest_api`:

```
from django.conf.urls import url, include
from rest_framework_nested import routers
from .views import *

router = routers.SimpleRouter()

# /organizers/12/events/1
router.register(r'organizers', OrganizerViewSet, base_name='organizers')
organizer_router = routers.NestedSimpleRouter(router, r'organizers', lookup='organizers')
organizer_router.register(r'events', EventViewSet, base_name='organizers-events')

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^', include(router.urls)),
    url(r'^', include(organizer_router.urls)),
]
```

Here's the `serializers.py` for `rest_api` app:

```
class EventSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Event
        fields = ['id', 'name', 'purpose', 'date_time', 'description', 'programme', 'entry_fee', 'status', 'comments']

class OrganizerSerializer(serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Organizer
        fields = ['id', 'first_name', 'middle_name', 'last_name', 'email', 'company_name', 'company_description', 'registered_on', 'status']

    events = serializers.HyperlinkedIdentityField(
        view_name = 'events_list',
        lookup_url_kwarg = 'organizer_pk'
    )
```

And finally, here's the `views.py` from the app `rest_api`:

```
from rest_framework import viewsets
from .models import *
from .serializers import *

class EventViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    def list(self, request, organizer_pk=None, name='events_list'):
        events = self.queryset.filter(organizer=organizer_pk)
        serializer = EventSerializer(events, many=True)
        return Response(serializer.data)

class OrganizerViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    def list(self, request, name='organizers_list'):
        data = Organizer.objects.all()
        serializer = OrganizerSerializer(data, many=True)
        return Response(serializer.data)
```

I'm sure there are many things broken in my code, and that's where I need help. The problem is I'm getting the following error:

`TypeError: list() got an unexpected keyword argument 'organizers_pk'`

I'm not sure what's wrong, and will appreciate some help!

Answer (score 1):

I got it working by changing the `EventViewSet` to the following:

```
def list(self, request, organizers_pk=None, name='events_list'):
    events = self.queryset.filter(organizer=organizers_pk)
    serializer = EventSerializer(events, many=True)
    return Response(serializer.data)
```

I'm not sure why, but the expected keyword argument name is `organizers_pk`, whereas I had `organizer_pk`. I would like to know why this is so, but other than that my problem is solved for now.

Answer (score 0):

A little outdated answer, but you had:

`organizer_router = routers.NestedSimpleRouter(router, r'organizers', lookup='organizers')`

Whatever you put into `lookup`, ending up being prefix for parent resource pk.
In this case, changing your URL to:

`organizer_router = routers.NestedSimpleRouter(router, r'organizers', lookup='organizer')`

will do the job for you.